# Alternative to Switch Case in android

Tags: android, switch-statement

I have a `recyclerview with an 30 images and on click of particular image i am opening a new activity which shows a different image.I have uploaded my images to a server and accessing the image from there. When my activity is opened on click of`recyclerview` i am passing the position through intent so that i can know which image was clicked,then i am using switch case in my activity and load whatever image i want.I have written 30 cases of switch as i have 30 images.Is there any alternative to this.I don't want to use if and else if.

```
public class ModelLineUpAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ModelLineUpAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    private List<Bikers> bikersList;

    public ModelLineUpAdapter(List<Bikers> bikersList,Context context) {
        this.bikersList=bikersList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageView bikesImageView;
        public TextView nameTextView, priceTextView;
        private Button brocheurebutton;
        private final Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            bikesImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikelistitemImageview);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikelistitemname);
            priceTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikelistitemprice);
            brocheurebutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bikelistitembutton);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ModelLineUpInnerActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("position",getAdapterPosition());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.bikelistitem, null);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Bikers bikers = bikersList.get(position);
        holder.nameTextView.setText(bikers.getBikename());
        holder.priceTextView.setText(bikers.getBikeprice());

        Glide.with(context).load(bikers.getBikeImageUrl()).into(holder.bikesImageView);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //Log.i(TAG, "getItemCount: "+bikersList.size());
        return  bikersList == null ? 0 : bikersList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your code and explain how it couldn't be done with an array/database of indexes to images.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have 30 images in my recyclerview right so i am passing the position of item which was clicked.So  do i need to write 30 switch cases or is there a better approach?

Comment: implement click listener to your recyclerview

Comment: show your adapter class

Comment: @NileshRathod I have edited the question please have a look

Comment: What you need to shoe in your `ModelLineUpInnerActivity` @AnuradhaSawant

Comment: @NileshRathod I want to show images based on position of item clicked in recyclerview.I have 30 images in my recyclerview so should i write 30 switch cases?

Comment: no just pass image url with intent @AnuradhaSawant

Comment: the image of recyclerview is different than the image in ModelLineUpInnerActivity @NileshRathod

Comment: can you explain more @AnuradhaSawant

Answer (score 0):

just pass image url with intent and recieve in your `ModelLineUpInnerActivity`

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ModelLineUpInnerActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("position",getAdapterPosition());
            intent.putExtra("IMG",bikersList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getBikeImageUrl());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```